# Custom Search Result Page order by Category ID

Tags: tags, search, content-filtering

i have "developed" a Custom Tag Search using a Form, on the Result Page (Template Override) the found Items are shown as a accordion menu in there Categories. I expected the Categories would be shown by category ID unfortunately this is not the case, it seems like somehow it takes the standard Options from the Tag Component and orders it by Article Title. Which is leading that my Categories are bit being shown in the correct order.

Example searh url: http://www.ego.pc-helfer.eu/index.php?option=com_tags&view=tag&id[0]=4&id[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/glnuW.jpg)=5&id[2]=64&id[3]=67&id[4]=69&types[0]=1

What i would like to achieve is that Accordion Menu is arranged like this:
Silicondichtstoffe (CATID 13)
Beidseitig Klebende Butylbänder (CATID 18)
Kaschierte Butylbänder (CATID 31)
Butylbänder für Spezialanwendungen (CATID 32)
CONLOC Klebstoffe (CATID 36)

The Code/Template Override i am using is (had to add the code as a picture, to much was stripped out):

[image]

Now can i just use the filter_order in the form an add something like:
< ?php get $category['id'];? >

Comment: Pasting your code in an image makes it difficult for someone to read it, moreover much harder if someone wants to test your code to replicate your issue.

Comment: This i understand, but when i am trying to paste the code almost every thing is being stripped out therefore i saw no other option than posting a picture. If somebody needs the code for testing i am happy to provide them with it.

Comment: Are you using the core component or module search form as your call to action source?

Comment: No i am using a Custom Search Form, created with RSForms Pro